# Possibily unprofessional chewing habit

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior, behavior

I'm currently doing an unpaid intern in a medium sized company, to finish my studies and get my master degree in computer science. During my college years, I've developed the habit of chewing plastic sticks - the ones you use to mix up coffee and sugar (I'm talking about [those](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31tv5MrLvwL._SY355_.jpg) things, the correct name escapes my grasp currently).

I'm a coffee person and I generally meet with my colleagues during coffee breaks. This usually happens early in the morning and after lunch. On a typical day, I drink my coffee around 9 am and I tend to keep chewing on the plastic stick while I'm working, sometimes even up until lunch.

I try to avoid doing it while I'm with other people or while other people are talking to me, but I fear this habit may look unprofessional or even unclean.
I'd like your personal opinion on the matter.

To clarify, I didn't get any signals that this habit has been noticed by my colleagues/ my tutor, nor it seems frowned upon. It's just me wondering.

Comment: Some people will find it just plain gross. My wife is one who would. The simple solution is to supplant the habit with a more mainstream one, like gum chewing. as long as you aren't smacking your gum, nobody will think twice about that.

Comment: Probably a good thing to do is go to the bathroom and look at yourself chewing that stick in a mirror.  Never mind how you feel about stick-chewing - look at how other people see you.  What you feel like isn't necessarily what you look like.  You probably don't look like Clint Eastwood chewing a match....

Comment: @Pete I probably don't look like Clint Eastwood, but I don't look like a trash bag either. I had occasions to look at myself in the mirror, stick on, and I look acceptable to me; as far as my perception goes. To clarify, I'm not much different than someone holding a cigarette in their mouth (it is true i'm *biting* the plastic stick, but I don't do so mouth open, teeth flashing). Of course others may have a different opinion on this, hence the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing unprofessional about the habit as you've described it.  Now, if you were leaving half-chewed sticks around the office, had one in your mouth while you were talking to people, etc.  That would be a problem.

If anyone did see you, they'd simply assume you had recently quit smoking and developed a substitute habit.  You **may** want to try to curb it and substitute it with another habit, but I wouldn't worry too much unless and until something is said.

There are far worse habits.

Comment: Any habit where your hands are near your mouth will "wig out" most people I know.  Nasty habit.

Answer (score 6):

> I fear this habit may look unprofessional or even unclean. I'd like
>   your personal opinion on the matter.

Some may indeed interpret this habit as unprofessional or possibly unclean. It would be like someone chewing on a toothpick all day.

You should try to quit this habit if you can.

There are plenty of self-help books on the subject, plenty of websites (search for "How to break a habit"), and you could always consult your doctor.

As far as habits go, this isn't a big deal. But it still may benefit you to break it if you can. It certainly couldn't hurt to be rid of it.

Comment: In my personal opinion, this would look unprofessional.  When you take that stick out of your mouth to speak with someone, you're waving a pretty gross, spit-covered mangled, bit of plastic at them.  Leaving it in your mouth to speak is also pretty gross.

Answer (score 5):

In the privacy of your work space this is not a big deal, in any other situation it will look really gross, and I would urge you to break the habit.

Here is an article that offers some insight on this topic as a whole:  [Bad Office Habits](https://www.monster.com/career-advice/article/7-bad-habits-that-are-secretly-driving-your-co-workers-crazy)

( this is applicable as your hands are around your mouth. )

> Doing things that gross people out. This could be coming in when
>   you're coughing and sneezing like crazy, clipping your fingernails or
>   toenails, or picking your nose or fingernails and then touching a
>   piece of shared office equipment. "Even if I was not ick-factored out,
>   I would get germ-factored out," says Rothman.

I use a fidget spinner when I need to burn nervous energy, and I leave it at my desk when I get up.